# Can I join a Kubernetes Windows Node to an Active Directory?

Tags: windows, kubernetes, active-directory, nodes

Is anyone aware of challenges or restrictions on joining the Kubernetes Windows Nodes to an Active Directory?. I mean my question is not about integrating the active directory with the K8s RBAC, but rather from a lifecycle management perspective, patching and whatnot?

Thank you

EN

Answer (score 0):

In short we did joined the windows nodes to our AD. So far it seems that there are no impacts on Kubernetes, We'll continue to monitor the behaviour of those nodes and report back if we hit any hiccups.